# adding azure webrole to vnet and also make it publicly available

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have a webrole in azure. The webrole needs to talk to a DB which is in a VNET. 
If the webrole is not added to the same vnet, then the site cant talk to the sql DB. However, if I add the webrole to the same vnet, DB accessbility is not a problem, but I cant access the xyz.cloudapp.net site externally.
How do I add it to the vnet and also make the webrole available externally.

I am sure this is a common case and there would be ways to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Are your webrole instances available externally when the role is *not* a member of the vnet?

Comment: Yes they are available externally when not in vnet